# How to set "allow-file-access-from-files" in CEF4DELPHI?

Tags: cef4delphi

I'm trying to create a program that load a html page that is in a localfolder, and this page has implemented some javascript resources (ex:pdf.js) that load a local pdf file.

Every time that i tried to run the program i get this error: "Fetch API cannot load file....URL scheme "file" is not supported"
The local html file is loaded but the javascript cannot load the pdf.

I know there is the --allow-file-access-from-files flag, but i don't find the way to set this flag in Cef4delphi.

How I can set --allow-file-access-from-files flag on CEF4DELPHI?

Answer (score 0):

Set the GlobalCEFApp.AllowFileAccessFromFiles property to True before the GlobalCEFApp.StartMainProcess call in the DPR file and CEF4DElphi will add that flag for you automatically.

If you need to use any flag/switch that it's not available as a GlobalCEFApp property just call the GlobalCEFApp.AddCustomCommandLine procedure before the GlobalCEFApp.StartMainProcess call.

However, that Fetch API error is sometimes shown when you register a custom scheme. Try registering the "http" or "https" schemes instead.